# JRHtmlExporter is deprecated now. How to define the path for saving images?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

The *JRHtmlExporter* class is deprecated now (*JasperReports 6.x*).

I replaced the usage of this class with *HtmlExporter*. But I can not find equivalent function to replace `exporter.setParameter (JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_URI, imageURI);`. I need to set path for storing images for generated report (*html* file).

My old code:

```
JRHtmlExporter exporter = new JRHtmlExporter();

exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, filedReport);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, outputFileName);
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.BETWEEN_PAGES_HTML, "");
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);            
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_USING_IMAGES_TO_ALIGN, Boolean.TRUE);

String imageURI = "q?srvAction=ReportImage&img="+returnFileName.substring(3).replace("/", "%2F")+"_files"+"%2F";
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_URI,imageURI);
```

What will be the actual code for *JasperReports 6.x* for defining path to images?

Comment: hi @Alex K, I want to replace exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE); as follows:    SimpleHtmlReportConfiguration ReportConfig = new SimpleHtmlReportConfiguration();
   ReportConfig.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenRows(true);
   exporter.setConfiguration(ReportConfig ); but it does't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we can see from the javadoc the [*JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_URI*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRHtmlExporterParameter.html#IMAGES_URI) parameter is really deprecated and the [*HtmlExporterOutput.getImageHandler()*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/export/HtmlExporterOutput.html#getImageHandler()) method should be used instead of it.

#### Define the path where images are storing

We can use the implementation of [HtmlResourceHandler](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/HtmlResourceHandler.html) interface, for example *[WebHtmlResourceHandler](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/web/util/WebHtmlResourceHandler.html)*.

The example of using:

```
JRExporter exporter = new HtmlExporter();

exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
SimpleHtmlExporterOutput output = new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(out);
output.setImageHandler(new WebHtmlResourceHandler("/reports/image?image={0}"));
exporter.setExporterOutput(output);

exporter.exportReport();
```

#### Define where to save images during export

With help of *[FileHtmlResourceHandler](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/FileHtmlResourceHandler.html)* handler we can set the path for images for generated *html*

The example of using:

```
JRExporter exporter = new HtmlExporter();
// output file for generated html report
File file = new File(String.format("./out/%1$s_%2$s.html", report.getTemplateName(), new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date())));

ExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimpleHtmlExporterConfiguration();
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);

exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
SimpleHtmlExporterOutput exporterOutput = new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(file);
// the folder for storing images. It will be subfolder with name starting like generated html and ended with postfix "_images"
File resourcesDir = new File(file.getParent(), file.getName() + "_images");
// argument ({0}) will be replaced with the real image name
String pathPattern = resourcesDir.getName() + "/{0}";

exporterOutput.setImageHandler(new FileHtmlResourceHandler(resourcesDir, pathPattern));
exporter.setExporterOutput(exporterOutput);
exporter.exportReport();
```

The generated files and folders will be like this:

```
 ..                                         [Folder]
    image-test_20170504232649.html          [File]
    image-test_20170504232649.html_images   [Folder]
        img_0_0_0.png                       [File]
```

---

***Notes***:

The sample of using *HtmlResourceHandler* can be found [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/webapp/index.html#webapp)

Comment: String imageURI = "q?srvAction=ReportImage&img="+returnFileName.substring(3).replace("/", "%2F")+"_files"+"%2F";
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_URI,imageURI); working well on jasperreport 3.5.3 library. After upgrading to jasperreport 6.3.1 library. I did the way you suggested. But it does not work. Thanks

Comment: What is a value of `imageURI` you got?

Comment: It is the temporary path to save the image.  Example: q?srvAction=ReportImage&img=WEB-INF%2Ftemp%2Fqipman%2Ffg%2Fqipman-PoolStatistics-20170504_115538_249_0700.html_files%2F

Comment: `public static final JRHtmlExporterParameter IMAGES_URI` - `An URI to the folder where all the images are stored. It could also point to a different resource, such as an image servlet. It is used in the generated HTML to point to the actual location of the image in the  tag (as a file on disk or a web resource).` It is not temporary path to save the image. `I did the way you suggested. But it does not work.` - What is your new code?

Comment: Hi,
*When i use:
String imageURI = "q?srvAction=ReportImage&img="+returnFileName.substring(3).replace("/", "%2F")+"_files"+"%2F";
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_URI,imageURI);
It gives me 2 files:
http://localhost:8080/q?srvAction=Report&Loc=WEB-INF%2Ftemp%2Fqipman%2Ffg%2Fqipman-PoolStatistics-20170504_115538_249_0700.html (1)
http://localhost:8080/q?srvAction=ReportImage&img=WEB-INF%2Ftemp%2Fqipman%2Ffg%2Fqipman-PoolStatistics-20170504_115538_249_0700.html_files%2Fimg_0_0_18 (2)
(2) Is the link to the image.
(1) Is my report.

Comment: *When i use:
JRExporter exporter = new HtmlExporter();
exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
SimpleHtmlExporterOutput output = new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(out);
output.setImageHandler(new WebHtmlResourceHandler(imageURI"));
exporter.setExporterOutput(output);
exporter.exportReport();
It only creates (1) without creating (2)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this for Jasper Report 6.9.0, this is the default method

```
JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(jasperPrint, jasperPrint.getName() + ".html");
```

But if you want to configure image resource handler and any other configuration, try this

```
HtmlExporter exporter = new HtmlExporter();
File destFile = new File(jasperPrint.getName() + ".html");

exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));

HtmlReportConfiguration reportConfig = getHTMLReportConfig();
exporter.setConfiguration(reportConfig);

HtmlExporterConfiguration exporterConfig = getHTMLExporterConfig();
exporter.setConfiguration(exporterConfig);

SimpleHtmlExporterOutput output = new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(destFile);
HtmlResourceHandler imageHandler = new WebHtmlResourceHandler(
                request.getContextPath() + "/jasper/image?image={0}");
output.setImageHandler(imageHandler);
exporter.setExporterOutput(output);

exporter.exportReport();
```

And this is configuration for HTMLExporter and HTMLReport

```
private HtmlExporterConfiguration getHTMLExporterConfig() {
    return new HtmlExporterConfiguration() {

        @Override
        public Boolean isOverrideHints() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Boolean isFlushOutput() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getHtmlHeader() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getHtmlFooter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        // biar tidak ada paging (khusus html)
        @Override
        public String getBetweenPagesHtml() {
            return "";
        }
    };
}

private HtmlReportConfiguration getHTMLReportConfig() {
    return new HtmlReportConfiguration() {

        @Override
        public Boolean isOverrideHints() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer getStartPageIndex() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public JRExportProgressMonitor getProgressMonitor() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer getPageIndex() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer getOffsetY() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer getOffsetX() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public JRHyperlinkProducerFactory getHyperlinkProducerFactory() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public ExporterFilter getExporterFilter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer getEndPageIndex() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Boolean isWrapBreakWord() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Boolean isWhitePageBackground() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Boolean isUseBackgroundImageToAlign() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        // biar gak terlalu banyak white space
        @Override
        public Boolean isRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenRows() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public Boolean isIgnorePageMargins() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public Boolean isIgnoreHyperlink() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Boolean isEmbeddedSvgUseFonts() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Boolean isEmbedImage() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Boolean isConvertSvgToImage() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Boolean isAccessibleHtml() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Float getZoomRatio() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public HtmlSizeUnitEnum getSizeUnit() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public HtmlBorderCollapseEnum getBorderCollapseValue() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getBorderCollapse() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

See this http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRHtmlExporterParameter.html